# How to trigger Spark Java Web Framework request programmatically

Tags: java, spark-java

Is there a way for Spark Framework to trigger request programmatically? Say we have

```
http.get("/hello/:route_param") { "Hello Spark!" }
```

How it could be called, with proper `path`, `query`, `body` etc, something like:

```
http.call(
  url  = "/hello/alex?a=b", 
  body = "{ value: 20 }"
) // => "Hello Spark!"
```

P.S.

I need it to add batch `/batch` route - so it will be possible to call it with the list of other routes and parameters and get back list of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "programmatically" you mean "without firing up an HTTP server and performing an HTTP request" than I think the answer is **no**. Spark does not provide such a capability out of the box.

There are a few possible workarounds:

1. You could start Spark in your application and fire an HTTP request. An example of this approach is in an [integration test](https://github.com/mthmulders/spark-flash/blob/master/src/test/java/spark/flash/FlashIT.java) I wrote for my Spark add-on
2. Use [MockRunner's Servlet module](https://mockrunner.github.io/) to create a (fake) `HttpServletRequest`. Use `RequestResponseFactory.create(HttpServletRequest)` to turn that into a Spark `Request`. Similarly for responses. Refactor the Spark `Route` to be a separate class, and invoke that using the `Request` and `Response` variables that you just created.